# Getting argument values from NSInvocation

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Could someone please explain how to go about getting the values passed to a non-existant method that is being intercepted when using:

```
+ (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation;

+ (NSMethodSignature *)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)aSelector;
```

Given a message like:

```
[SomeClass doSomething:@"theThing" withSomething:@"aParam"];
```

I can get the method signature without a problem but I am terribly confused about how to get the values that were passed in with it.

Am I totally off base in when I should use these methods or just missing something?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[`-[NSInvocation getArgument:atIndex:]`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000212-getArgument_atIndex_)

So in your case, you would use it like:

```
__unsafe_unretained NSString * firstArgument = nil;
__unsafe_unretained NSString * secondArgument = nil;
[theInvocation getArgument:&firstArgument atIndex:2];
[theInvocation getArgument:&secondArgument atIndex:3];
NSLog(@"Arguments: %@ and %@", firstArgument, secondArgument);
```

Remember that `self` and `_cmd` are arguments 0 and 1.

Comment: Do firstArgument & secondArgument need to be __unsafe_unretained under ARC?

Comment: @pshah Absolutely, your comment has solved the issue I've been debugging for the past few hours. Thank you!

Comment: Yes - you must use __unsafe_retained