# Warning when trying to get NSString type argument from NSInvocation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to get argument passed in, I already got the NSInvocation instance. I tried:

```
NSString *firstArg;
[invocation getArgument:&firstArg atIndex:2];// Warning here.
```

But I got warning:
[image]

How to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getArgument` requires `Nonnull` , you have not initialized your `NSString` so,

change your code as below:

```
NSString *firstArg=nil;
[invocation getArgument:&firstArg atIndex:2];
```

Comment: Since I see it requires Nonnull, so I didn't assign nil to it. Now I get confused

Comment: check answer here: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/2166797/5575752](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2166797/5575752)